# property java.protocol.handler.pkgs

Tags: java, web-services, unix, soap, oc4j

I have a soap client that calls a web service through ssl, when I add this line:

`System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs","com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");`

the client works with a rate of 15 calls per second, when removing it the speed goes down to 1.5 per second (10 times slower), I am using java 4 and tomcat 6 on a windows machine for my development environment

I'd be happy with this but when deploying the same code to oracle application server 10g on a unix machine the speed is always 1.5 per second weather I am setting the property or not!

Can any one figure out what is going on here?!

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle App Server, try using oracle.mds.net.protocol instead of com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol. This is the value used by default in WebLogic, I have never used OAS so I can't advise.